# VMWARE rest api tag association

Tags: rest, vmware, vsphere

I'm trying to associate vmware tags to vitual machines over the rest api for vsphere 6.5. The api documentation for this method is lacking: https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/1cd28284-3b72-4885-9e31-d1c6d9e26686/71ef7304-a6c9-43b3-a3cd-868b2c236c81/doc/operations/com/vmware/cis/tagging/tag_association.attach-operation.html

In particular I'm struggling to find any information on the object id type and what should be passed as the two ids (different sources give different answers). Any information on the formats and content of these fields would be appreciated.

This is my current post. The ids are being pulled from the api during virtual machine creation.

```
POST /rest/com/vmware/cis/tagging/tag-association/id:urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceTag:<hex number>:GLOBAL?~action=attach
```

Json encoded body:

```
{"object_id":{"id":"Elstree_vm-<4 digit number>","type":"VirtualMachine"}}
```

The api is returning 404s and the error Tagging object  not found, which is of type cis.tagging.objectNotFound.error.

Comment: Where did you find the list of types to get `VirtualMachine`?  I was searching for hours trying to find this, your fragment helped me out... I'd been using `string` like the API doc example at https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/1cd28284-3b72-4885-9e31-d1c6d9e26686/71ef7304-a6c9-43b3-a3cd-868b2c236c81/doc/structures/com/vmware/vapi/std/dynamic_id-structure.html -- thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out

The correct post format:

```
POST /rest/com/vmware/cis/tagging/tag-association/id:urn:vmomi:InventoryServiceTag:<hex number>:GLOBAL?~action=attach
```

Json encoded body

```
{"object_id":{"id":"vm-<4 digit number>","type":"VirtualMachine"}}
```

Comment: `com.vmware.vapi.rest.unsupportedMediaType`

Answer (score 0):

I'v got this working code from VMware in powershell (with powercli modules):

```
$creds = Get-Credential
$vCenter = 'vcenter.fqdn'
$tagName = "WebServer"
$vmName = "web01"

Connect-CisServer -Server $vCenter -Credential $creds
Connect-ViServer -Server $vCenter -Credential $creds

$tagSvc = Get-CisService -Name com.vmware.cis.tagging.tag
$tagList = $tagSvc.list()
$tags = @()
foreach ($t in $tagList) {
    $tags += $tagSvc.Get($t)
}
$tag = $tags | where {$_.Name -eq $tagName}
$vm = Get-VM -Name $vmName
$tagAssoc = Get-CisService -Name com.vmware.cis.tagging.tag_association
$objId = $tagAssoc.Help.attach.object_id.Create()
$objId.type = $vm.ExtensionData.MoRef.Type
$objId.id = $vm.ExtensionData.MoRef.Value
$tagAssoc.attach($tag.id.Value, $objId)

$attachedTags = $tagAssoc.list_attached_tags($objId)
foreach ($at in $attachedTags) {
    $tagSvc.Get($at)
}
```